# How to transform date-based CSV file into a spreadsheet?

Tags: linux, excel, csv, transformation

I have a file like this:

```
100,2015-09-01
100,2015-09-02
105,2015-09-01
645,2017-01-01
```

It's just a number and a date separated by a comma. It has 20000 lines.

I want to transform this file into a spreadsheet (Google, Excel, LibreOffice, any format, even a CSV) that says for each number if it appears for a given date. For example:

```
ID  | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-02 | 2017-01-01
----+------------+------------+-----------
100 | YES        | YES        | NO
105 | YES        | NO         | NO
645 | NO         | NO         | YES
```

How can I do that?

I'm on Linux, so command line utilities like `sed`, `awk`, etc are available and preferred as a way to automate this.

Comment: For Excel, you could just open or import the csv file, then split it using the text to columns wizard; add some column headers to your original, and then use something like a pivot table to get the output you want.  Give it a try and post back with details if you run into problems. Also, Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Or, you could write a VBA routine to do the whole thing, and possible have more flexibility in defining the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Could make it work using AWK.

```
awk -F "," '{
    numbers[$1]
    dates[$2]
    number_date[$1,$2]
} END {
    for (number in numbers) printf ";%s", number;
    printf "\n"
    for (date in dates) {
       printf "%s", date
       for (number in numbers)
          if ((number SUBSEP date) in number_date) printf ";YES"
          else printf ";NO"
       printf "\n"
    }
}' input.csv | sort > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV equivalent to the data you post (to be read by excel) is:

```
ID,2015-09-01,2015-09-02,2017-01-01
100,YES,YES,NO
105,YES,NO,NO
645,NO,NO,YES
```

as you can easily test if you create that spreadsheet and export it to CSV format.

So, to be able to read it as CSV, you have first to convert your data from the format you posted to the format I post above, and then import it as CSV.  This can be done with the AWK script that has been posted here also by @ThiagoNegri, so I'm not going to repeat it again.